# Importing a model in Django that shares it's name between two different applications problem

Tags: python, django, models

I have two apps one named "challenge" another named "stats"; within the models.py files of both I have classes named Team.   They serve two complete seperate purposes.  When I import from another app

```
from stats.models import Team
```

it will only and always import the Team model from challenge, rather than from stats. If I import from challenge

```
from challenge.models import Team
```

it will import correctly from challenge.  When I use the shell I get the following:

```
>>> from stats.models import Team
>>> Team
<class 'challenge.models.Team'>
```

I thought it may have been within the order of applications in INSTALLED_APPS within the settings.py so I rearranged them to no avail.

Is there some weird circular dependency thing I'm not catching or is this a bug within Django?   What's going on?

Comment: How about a third idea?  This is a Very Bad Thing To Do.  Folks who have to maintain this after you win the lottery will hate you a lot and will rename that class within about an hour of you leaving.  Why not save them all the work?

Comment: Debug by printing out `type(Team)` in `stats/models.py`. If it's already challenge… then you might have imported it there somewhere or there is some other module setting stats.models.Team. Hard to tell without code.

Comment: Whether it's a good idea or not does not explain the original problem.  I've tried the type(Team) but that only outputs  <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'>

Comment: sorry, try `repr(Team)` instead

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
from challenge.models import Team as ChallengeTeam
from stats.models import Team as StatsTeam

ChallengeTeam
>>> <class 'challenge.models.Team'>

StatsTeam
>>> <class 'stats.models.Team'>
```